# What is the name of this machine learning problem?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, predictive-models

I am confronted to a particular type of problem that I do not know how to handle. And I cannot find any literature about this problem.

**Problem settings**

I have a dataset of $n$ sample points. Each point consists in a set of $m$ vectors of features, named $x^{(i)}_j \in \mathbb R^d$, for $1 \leq i \leq n$ and $1 \leq j \leq m$.

For set of vectors $(x^{(i)}_j)_{1 \leq j \leq m}$, the corresponding values $y^{(i)}_1 , ..., y^{(i)}_m \in \{-1 ; 1\}$ are available. Among the $m$ values, only one is equal to $1$, and the other are equal to $-1$.

**What I want the model to do**

I would like to learn a model from these data which gives for a new set of vectors $(x^{(0)}_j)_{1 \leq j \leq m}$, the corresponding values $y^{(0)}_1 , ..., y^{(0)}_m$. More precisely, I search for a model which returns:
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
p(y^{(0)}_1 > 0 | x^{(0)}_1 , ..., x^{(0)}_m ) \\
\vdots \\
p(y^{(0)}_m > 0 | x^{(0)}_1 , ..., x^{(0)}_m )
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

**My questions**

Does this problem have a name in the statistical literature?

Could you point me papers which treat that issue or algorithms which are able to learn this particular classification problem?

Answer (score 1):

You should consider [multinomial logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression).  It is, I think, exactly what you are looking for, assuming that all d choices are available to all subjects.

If that assumption doesn't hold, you should look in the literature for [discrete choice models](http://facweb.knowlton.ohio-state.edu/pviton/courses2/crp5700/5700-mlogit.pdf).  Be wary of the assumptions of these models, many require behavioral assumptions that are dubious.

Comment: The products can different for each user i, so that I think it cannot be seen as a multilabel classification problem.

Comment: Ah, in that case you should look up the literature on Discrete Choice models.  They have a variety of (conditional) multinomial logistic models that work when the set of available items differs.  Just be careful when choosing a model, that it makes sense for your situation (I don't trust many of the utility theory models, but that might be what you are stuck with).  [Here](http://facweb.knowlton.ohio-state.edu/pviton/courses2/crp5700/5700-mlogit.pdf) is a nice set of examples of discrete choice models in R.